# Running total with annotated querysets in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a running total template tag which looks like

```
from django.template import Library 

register = Library() 

@register.filter
def running_total(list, var_name):
    return sum(getattr(obj, var_name) or 0 for obj in list)
```

It works when I need a running total in normal querysets, but when I use a annotated queryset I get the exception `'dict' object has no attribute 'total'`.

When I print a normal queryset in my template I get `[<Item: Item #1>]`, but when I print a annotated queryset I get a list with a tuple `[{'total_amount': Decimal('0.00'), ...]`.

Should I somehow convert the list in my templatetag?

I've tried adding

```
list = list(list)
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: use a better name than `list`. you are overriding the default type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = []
for obj in list:
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        arr.append(obj[var_name] if var_name in obj else 0)
    else:
        arr.append(getattr(obj, var_name) or 0)
return sum(arr)
```

The reason is that elements in annotated queryset is not model instance anymore, it's dict.